# how to filter data from MYSQL database table last every 30 seconds in django query?

Tags: django

My database table name is `tripcomment`:

```
mysql> select * from orbit_tripcomments;

+----+------------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | comment                | citymap_id | ip_address | user_id | posted              |
+----+------------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
|  2 | very nice comment               508 | 127.0.0.1  |     168 | 2014-11-20 08:25:19 |
|  3 | I make plan for visite |        508 | 127.0.0.1  |     168 | 2014-11-20 08:33:17 |
|  4 | i make a trip of manali|        508 | 127.0.0.1  |     168 | 2014-11-19 10:17:17 |
|  5 | i make a trip of manali|        508 | 127.0.0.1  |     168 | 2014-11-20 10:18:26 |
```

My django query is:

```
from datetime import datetime    
from datetime import timedelta

tt = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

t_comment = models.tripcomments.objects.filter(citymap_id=parent_mapid,
                                               posted__gte=tt)
```

But it returns a blank list.

Comment: Are you looking for trip comments in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `datetime` instance for `DateTime` field, not string:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

results = Item.objects.filter(pub_date__lt=datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5))
```